# My Mysterious App_Data Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a MVC 4 Web Application that runs nicely.

I added a line like

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
{
     <td>Entered by</td>
}
```

Locally no problems.

Clean it...or Hard Publish it (anything changed in Controller) and ***WHAM!!***

> Access denied creating App_Data subdirectory
>
> Description: For security reasons, the identity 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET
>   v4.0' (under which this web application is running), does not have
>   permissions to create the App_Data subdirectory within the application
>   root directory. ASP.NET stores the Microsoft SQL Express Database file
>   used for services such as Membership and Profile in the App_Data
>   subdirectory of your application.
>
> To grant the necessary permissions, follow these steps: In Windows
>   Explorer, navigate to your application's directory. Create a folder
>   named "App_Data": Right-click, choose "New" menu item, choose "Folder"
>   sub-menu item, and then type "App_Data" (without quotes). Right-click
>   on the "App_Data" subdirectory, within your application and select the
>   "Properties" menu item. In the "Properties" dialog box that opens,
>   select the "Security" tab.
>
> Click Add
>
> In the "Enter the object names to select" box, enter 'IIS
>   APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0' (without quotes).
>
> Click OK
>
> Make sure the account name is selected and then under Allow, check
>   Write
>
> Click OK
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

**When i log out and log back in to that website, the error goes away and that page works great.**

I am using the built in membership directed to a local Server expressed by the following

**On LocalHost:**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog=aspnet-P****aker-2013062000841;
Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**On Production:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog=aspnet-Prop*****30******1;
User Id=Pr###A;Password=K###3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  
xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</connectionStrings>
```

***Here is the mysterious part.***
There is no App_Data directory at all...and hey...after all...why should there have been in the first place, i ain't using one, i've got my own server handling membership.

If there is a kind heart out there, won't you lend a helping finger or two or ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using SQL Express, which creates the data file for its database in `App_Data`. When Entity Framework tries to create your database on production, you get that error because the trust level doesn't allow it to store the data file where it's set to. Use a real SQL Server instance in production. That'll fix this error, but it's also just what you do. Don't use SQL Express for anything but development and testing.

Comment: But  there is no App_Data directory there? and the page eventually works after log in/out?

Comment: It's trying to *create* the directory. That's why it fails.

Comment: Have no clue. You're using a different data source for membership, so there's some reason it's attempting to create the database in one instance and not the other. That's besides the point, though. The error is explicit, and the solution is either to change the trust level (bad idea), create the directory manually and and give the IIS  User read/write access to it (still not a great idea), or *use a real database for production*.

Comment: hmmm...interesting, i am more concerned out what is unique about refreshing that login session, which causes the problem to go away, but i hope to try your server change approach +1 for now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Go to advanced settings in application pool.

Make Identity **NetworkService**

Create folder App_Data and grant writeable access to **NetworkService**

Add a user **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE** in your SQL Database and grant it writeable access on your Membership table.

**Still need to Log out / in to get role access after a publish, just got rid of ugly error**